# Refresh grid from another UI in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a main Layout that contains another UI with grid and a button. This grid shows the data of a table of my database. With  the button a wizard gets open, where i can create a new entry to this database. When i close the wizard with a button click, i want the grid to refresh in order to show also the newly added entry. Everythin works fine, including the storage to my database, except the refresh of my grid.

So i have the UI

```
   public class MainLayout{
   ...
   public void refreshGrid()
   {
      this.grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
   }

   }
```

where my grid is defined. I already implemented the refresh method.In there is also the button to create a new entry. When i click this button the next UI gets called.
This UI contains the general layout of the wizard, with a tab bar.

```
public class WizardLayout{
}
```

In one of those tabs there is finally the UI with the input fields to create the entry. There is also the button to save it to the database.

```
public class CreateEntry{
...
private void button_onClick(ClickEvent<Button> event)
{
...
}
}
```

In this button click method the logic is implemented to save it. And after that i would like to call the refresh method from the first UI in order to refresh it. How do i do that, so that it works?

Please remember, everything else works. So my only problem is to refresh the grid because it does not automatically. I have to click the refresh button in my browser to make it work.

Comment: Check out guava Eventbus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that while not incorrect, your use of the term UI might be confusing in a Vaadin context, as it's usually used to refer to Vaadin `UI` objects, of which there is generally one per tab. Communication between Vaadin UIs is more complex than your use case.

There are plenty of solutions for this, the easiest is probably to pass an instance of your `MainLayout` to your wizard.

In that case, the classes will be tightly coupled, i.e. both depend on each other.

A better way is with some kind of listener or callback. This can be made quite complex, but in the easiest case you just pass a callback that will be run on save.

`WizardLayout.java`

```
private final Runnable saveCallback;

public WizardLayout(Runnable saveCallback) {
    this.saveCallback = saveCallback;
}

private void button_onClick(ClickEvent<Button> event) {
    ...
    saveCallback.run();
}
```

`MainLayout.java`

```
new WizardLayout(this::refreshGrid);
```

Comment: The button click event is in the CreateEntry class. So everything you added to WizardLayout has to be in the CreateEntry, am i right? SO what do i have to change in the wizardLayout?

Comment: Passing the instance of my mainlayaout worked, but i would like to understand the last solution you mentioned. Could you please describe it again?

Comment: Then the WizardLayout would need to pass the listener to the CreateLayout. It's hard to say without knowing all the details of the project, since if your WizardLayout is generic, you might not want to couple it to the CreateLayout either.

Comment: What do i have to change when i have parameters for my method refreshGrid? For Example refreshGrid(String name). When i do `new WizardLayout(this::refreshGrid)` there is the error "The constructor WizardLayout(this::refreshGrid) is undefined.

Comment: Then you can change the `Runnable` to a `Consumer<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataprovider using [in-memory items](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider.html#displaying-in-memory-data), or do you use a [callback dataprovider with lazy loading](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider.html#lazy-loading-data-from-a-backend-service)?

You are probably using an in-memory dataprovider. This is the case, when you load your items from the database and put them in the grid with

```
grid.setItems(fooService.findAll());
```

Calling `grid.getDataProvider().refresh()` will only refresh the items that are already set. Since you have a new item to display, you have to fetch all items *again* from the DB with your service.

```
grid.setItems(fooService.findAll());
grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
```

If you're using a callback dataprovider with lazy loading, then I think just refreshing the dataprovider should be enough. I don't know enough about lazy loaded dataproviders to provide a solution to this issue but I do believe this issue should not arise in the first place if using a callback dataprovider

Comment: I don't use `setItems()`, just a data provider with fetch type eager.